# How to run 'source ~/.my_commands.sh' in windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-prompt

I want to run `source ~/.my_commands.sh` but I am not able to. I have tried PowerShell and CommandPrompt these are the errors I get. If it is not possible to run this command in windows, is there an alternate solution?:

PowerShell:

[image: Picture of error]

Command Prompt:

[image: Picture of error]

This is what my_commands.sh contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

function create() {
    cd
    source .env
    python create.py $1
    cd $FILEPATH$1
    git init
    git remote add origin git@github.com:$USERNAME/$1.git
    touch README.md
    git add .
    git commit -m "Initial commit"
    git push -u origin master
    code .
}
```

Comment: `source` is a *nix shell command. It does not work on Windows. Neither do `.sh` files, which are *nix shell scripts.

Comment: Is there an alternative way I can achieve this in Windows?

Comment: No idea, because I don't know what's in `.my_commands.sh`. You should [edit] your question to ask that one instead.

Comment: Try `bash.exe .my_commands.sh` if you have installed WSL or WSL2… For more options `bash.exe --help`.

Comment: You could rewrite in Powershell, won't take long as long as git and python are on your path.

Comment: There is no source command on PowerShell or cmd. If you want bash functionality you can get WSL and then if you use `bash -c "source ./my_commands.sh"` you will get your results. As for PowerShell, without WSL there is no built-in bash functionality, but with you can do `sh ./my_commands.sh`

Comment: Don't you mean `source .env/bin/activate` for activating the virtual env instead of `source .env`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to run .sh scripts on windows is to use git bash. Download and install [git for windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win), go to the folder where you have your .sh script, right click, select "git bash here" and run the script like this:

```
./my_commands.sh
```